# using NSNotification with CoreData

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nsnotification

I have an `TO-DO` list app that I would like each entry in the app to have the ability to have a notification set for it. I would also like the user to have the ability to change the time that notification is schedule to deploy. My question is what kind of data would I store in `CoreData` to make that happen? I'm new to `CoreData` and `NSNotification` and I'm just not sure if I just have to save the date data the notification is scheduled for?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean UILocalNotification?

Answer (score 1):

There must be some information regarding your `TO DO`  item like some text, reminder date etc. Make an entity for it and after adding a `TO DO` in core data you can schedule `UILocalNotification` for it, assign the `reminder date` in the `fireDate` property of  `UILocalNotification`. Check the following link to get  started.

[UILocalNotification Tutorial](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/?p=292)

[Core Data Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/115695/getting-started-with-core-data-tutorial)